# Filter out *.spec.ts files in the VSCode Explorer?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to temporarily filter out `*.spec.ts` files in the VSCode explorer via the UI?

Comment: Yes - I think I'm looking for the exclude extension.

Comment: Tried it but it does not work ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can modify your workspace settings (ctrl+shift+p and search for `workspace settings` and once in the workspace settings search for `exclude`) and add

```
"files.exclude": {
  "**/*.spec.ts": true,
}
```